# How can I get all the property-names of different nodes?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I want to get the effect like using Oracle.

For example,I hava two tables: `Student`, `Tearcher`. I can get all the column names of the two tables using SQL.

Now, I have two nodes: one with label `Student` with Name, age, sex, grade properties, another with label `Teacher` and Name, sex, salary properties.

Can I get all the property names with Neo4jClient using Cypher?

Thx Z.Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`keys`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-keys) function, if you want to get the properties by label you could match accordingly with a query like:

```
MATCH (a:Student) WITH keys(a) as k UNWIND k as x RETURN DISTINCT x
```

Will return all the existing properties on the nodes labeled as `Student`

Explanation:

- The query matches all the nodes labeled as `Student`.
- It extracts the property keys of the nodes using [`keys`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-keys), then passes them by as arrays [`WITH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html)
- [`UNWIND`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html) catches the arrays and splits them into single rows
- [`RETURN DISTINCT`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html#return-unique-results) returns the property names as rows avoiding duplicates

---

## Example

On C# using [Neo4jClient](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) the code to execute that query would be something like:

```c#
client = new GraphClient(new Uri(connString), dbuser, dbpass);
client.Connect();
var results = (Result)client.Cypher.Match("(a:Student)")
                                   .With("keys(a) as k")
                                   .Unwind("k as x")
                                   .ReturnDistinct<Result>("x")
                                   .Results.ToList()
```

Having a class setup for results like this:

```c#
public class Result
{
    public string x { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Max Rasguido,your solution is correct,but I don't know how tranlate it to C#.

Comment: Added a C# implementation of the query